# Getting the script tag using getElementsByTagName inconsistent across browsers

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var script_obj = document.getElementsByTagName('script')
        alert(typeof script_obj);
    });
</script>
```

When I run this in Firefox (v21) and Chrome (v29) I get `object` as the result, but in Safari (v5) I get `function`.

Why is this?!

In the rest of my script I'm iterating through `script_obj` to get the `.src` data, but my `count` function that determines the length of the `haystack` (i.e. `script_obj`) has a check that returns `false` if the `haystack` is not an `array` or an `object`, so it is failing in Safari. Is there another way I can do this instead of using `document.getElementsByTagName('script')`?!

Comment: Before changing anything: do you have a semicolon after `var` statement in you production code? If not, please add it, and test again.

Comment: just to add to the question, the result is `object` in IE10 and Opera15 also.

Comment: There's a `document.scripts` HTMLCollection available at least in IE, FF, Chrome and Opera hmm... 12.

Comment: Thanks guys. Actually the `count` function returned `false` when `!array && !object`, so I updated it to check `.length` as well, and return `false` only when the length is invalid too. It works ok now. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName()` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Although a NodeList is not an Array, it does have a length property just like an Array. So you don't need to do anything special to count the number of items in it. Not sure what your count function is doing, but you can just do this:

```
> var script_obj = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
> alert(script_obj.length); // will alert '22' or whatever
```

Comment: But other types also have a `.length`, like `function` and `string`. I would assume OP is trying to ensure that an array-like structure is being passed.

Comment: Thanks for the brief and clear answer. I added an extra test for this to my `count` function.